# Is it OK to set the timezone in my php app to something other than the actual location of the app?

Tags: php, mysql, lamp

I have a legacy php app that I am supporting, and we are moving this app from a hosted provider located in the mid-west (CST) to our local network on the east coast (EST). I noticed when I moved the app that many of the dates and times were incorrect. This is a scheduling/calendar app that uses unix time stamps stored in the db (mysql). I found that if I add `date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');` to the applications config file, then all is well. I did some testing by adding new data to the application and all seems well. My question is, is it OK to leave the application with the default time zone set to America/Chicago, even though its running in EST? If I do, what repercussions might I face in the future?

Comment: As long as you store all of your datetime values as timestamps and always make sure to keep timezones in consideration when working with dates and times you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off setting the timezone in the OS so that you wont run into any conflicts. MySQL right now wont agree on the timezone which can be problematic if you have queries that use MySQL's date functions. Or any other software that manipulates dates for you, such as e-mail.

Comment: I can't change the timezone in the OS due to other applications running on this server.

Answer (score 0):

It is always advisable to use GMT datetime while storing data and convert it to desired time zone after retriving it.

In your case, setting default timezone in php will work but it will fail when some of your queries are using now() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. If possible, change machine timezone to CST to avoid any unknown problems.